# ImageMagick static compilation with another project gives linker errors

Tags: c++, imagemagick, static-linking, magick++

I've downloaded the ImageMagick source, compiled the wizard to create a Visual Studio solution for static linkage, and included the static library Magick++ project in my sample project (code below). I've also added a dependency on that project and included the .lib file in the solution, nothing helps.

```
#include <Magick++.h>

int main()
{
    Magick::Image image;
    bool test = image.isValid();
    return 0;
}
```

This gives several linker errors, such as:

unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall Magick::Image::~Image(void)" (__imp_??1Image@Magick@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

Why can't it find the implementation?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may rise from that you are using different compiler than the library was compiled with. As your compiler is fairly new, it's very likely it uses different name mangling and can't find method signatures inside the library.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to linking the ImageMagick static libraries is to ensure you link **ALL** the dependant static libraries as well!

Once you have compiled the solution for ImageMagick static libraries, go to the 'VisualMagick' folder (within the ImageMagick cloned repository) then to to the 'lib' folder there you will see all the *_DB_*.lib and *_RL_*.lib files for Debug and Release.

You need to include those names in the 'Additional Dependencies' section for both Release and Debug.

You must also ensure you have the Library folder path in the 'Additional Library Directories' for both Release and Debug.

Another key aspect is to ensure the libraries are built by the same compiler for the same platform architecture as your own application .. (WIN32 or x64).

Answer (score 0):

This error is strange - The compiler is looking for a function from a DLL (__declspec(dllimport)). Are you sure you are using the right header files ?